# Нужно вывести на экран 20 случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне java

Tags: java, случайные-числа

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    int y, c, b;
    y = a.nextInt();
    c = a.nextInt();
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        b = r.nextInt(c) + y;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Мой код выводит случайные числа без диапозона, не могу понять что не так, и значания могут быть отрицательными

Comment: Не надо использовать `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())`. Используйте просто `new Random()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = 0;
    int y = a.nextInt();
    int c = a.nextInt();
    int diff = c - y;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        result = r.nextInt(diff) + y;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Здесь выводится результат не включая число `c`. Если нужно выводить и его, то к переменной `diff` нужно добавить 1, вот так:

```
int diff = c - y + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    int y, c, b;
    y = a.nextInt();
    c = a.nextInt();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
       System.out.println(r.nextInt(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.