# Как создать метод, который заполняет массив float[] рандомными числами в заданом диапазоне?

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа, вывод, float

***Вопрос***: как решить задачу?

***Задача***: нужно создать метод который заполняет массив `float[]` рандомными числами в диапазоне от 32.0 до 40.0

***Проблема:*** не понимаю как взаимодействуют класс `Main` и метод `main()`, в котором создают массив `float[] temperatureData` с классом `Hospital` метод `generatePatientsTemperatures()`. Как заполнить массив `float[] temperatureData`, что лежит в `class Main` методом `generatePatientsTemperatures()` из класса `Hospital`?

***Важно:*** Класс `Main` и все что в нем, подано задачей и не может быть изменено. Можно лишь менять код внутри фигурных скобок метода `generatePatientsTemperatures()`. Моя попытка не работает.

***Код:***

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[] temperatureData = Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures(30);
    System.out.println(temperatureData);
}

public class Hospital {
    public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {
        
        // моя попытка 
        float minTemp = 32f
        float maxTemp = 40f;
        float[] array = new float[patientsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (float) (Math.random() * maxTemp - minTemp) + minTemp;
        }
        // моя попытка
        return array;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно вывести на экран 20 случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572241/); [Заполнение массива случайными числами из диапазона `[-15,15]` с помощью Math.random](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434704/); [Случайное число в диапазоне от -10 до 10 в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378896/)

Comment: @NowhereMan На дуппликаты вообще то не ставят -1.

Comment: @RomanC, а я и не ставил

Comment: @NowhereMan Потом в дупее используются целые числа, а не вещественные.

Comment: Представленный код выводит что-то вроде `[F@ee7d9f1`,  а не содержимое массива, независимо от реализации метода `generatePatientsTemperatures` и заполнения числами.

Comment: Можно было бы как-то попробовать `Arrays.toString()`, но с учётом требований `"Класс Main и все что в нем, подано задачей и не может быть изменено"` как мне кажется будет излишним @NowhereMan.

Comment: [F@ee7d9f1 - выводит консоль. Метод не заполняет массив, а как это сделать, ума не приложу. За что оценка -2?

Comment: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784)

Comment: @YehorZinchenko, Откуда вы знаете, что _метод не заполняет массив_?  Ваш код вполне себе заполняет массив, но числами из неправильного диапазона.  Ваша проблема в этом?  Или всё же в неправильном выводе массива, реализованном в коде, который запрещено менять.

Comment: [F@ee7d9f1 -это адрес массива, а не его содержимое. -2 ставят за то, что не поставил галочку на правильный ответ, и не сделал это вовремя.

Comment: Всех благодарю. Полезные и нужные комментарии. Ответ получен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array[i] = minTemp + (float) (Math.random() * (maxTemp - minTemp));
```

ты не учитываешь правильный диапазон для случайных чисел, когда вычитаешь minTemp из maxTemp в выражении Math.random() * (maxTemp - minTemp). Это должно быть просто (maxTemp - minTemp) * Math.random() + minTemp.

Comment: Благодарю, очень полезный комментарий! Однако, основной вопрос еще открыт. Массив не заполняется значениями

Answer (score 1):

Первая ошибка в том, что числа заполняются в массив неправильно. Это вызвано тем что неверные значения присваиваются элементам массива, поскольку неправильно вычисляется значение случайного вещественного числа из заданного диапазона. Для того, чтобы решить задачу надо прочитать следующее:

[Генерация случайных чисел в Java](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/generaciya-sluchajnyx-chisel-v-java/).

> 2. А что если нам необходимо сгенерировать числа из другого диапазона, отличного от [0;1)?
>    Легко! Давайте формально запишем наш диапазон: [a;b). То есть нижняя граница а, верхняя b. Тогда для генерации вещественных чисел в заданном диапазоне нужно записать следующее:
>
> ( Math.random() * (b-a) ) + a

То есть, код надо переписать так, что

```
float minTemp = 32f
float maxTemp = 40f;
float[] array = new float[patientsCount];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
   array[i] = (float) (Math.random() * (maxTemp - minTemp) + minTemp);
```

---

Вторая ошибка в методе `main()`, который не выводит елементы массива в консоль. Для того, чтобы это сделать, нужно использовать цикл `for` или использовать доступные средства для вывода содержимого массива в консоль.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temperatureData));
```

---

Вообще говоря, количество способов распечатки массива достаточно большое. Об этом можно прочитать в [Как распечатать массив на Java](https://javascopes.com/how-to-print-an-array-in-java-27992674/).

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.